# @Assert\NotBlank Not working

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a formular that I want to validate. The user should not be able to leave fields unfilled and that why I use `@Assert\NotBlank` but it does not seem to be working this is a part of my entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="device", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="This value cannot be empty!")
     */
    private $device;
...
```

And in the controler I'm using formbuilder from symfony like this:

```
...
     $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('device', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Device:',
            'attr' => array('placeholder' =>'Dell 2407WPB - Monitor'),
            'required' => true,
            ))
...
```

Do you have any suggestions about what may I be doing wrong? I've been stuck in this problem too long.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't you forget to call isValid() in your controller ? Here, your code seems to be correct.

Comment: yes I do, I use  `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the form with `createFormBuilder`, you should pass an instance of the entity.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(new MyEntity())
```

so that the form know the class that holds the data (and his constraints).